# USB charge in android 4.2.2

Tags: usb, charging

I have an android 4.2.2 phone. When I connect it to my desktop PC, it is not charging (Showing as charging and disconnected repeatedly). Checked by changing USB cable, connecting to different PC, connecting to different phones with same cable etc. Using same cable I can charge other mobiles like lumia, android 4.1 phones. Also I can charge my phone with same cable through charger. When I google it, I found that USB charge only option is removed in 4.2.2 (It was der in earlier versions). My model is XOLO Q1000 Opus and android version is 4.2.2. Please help me

Comment: You're saying the phone continually goes into and out of charge mode, no matter what cable or computer you use? Since you say it works fine with AC. I suspect that perhaps USB just doesn't provide enough power to charge the device.

Comment: Have you installed the USB drivers for your phone? Without the phone can only retrieve 100 mA => 0.5 Watt.

Comment: @Robert do you have any further info or links on this, sounds useful to know about!

Comment: @RossC That is written in the USB standard. Before the device is initialized the maximum power the device is allowed to use is limited to 100mA. Only when a charger is detected it can use as much power as it can get.